# Multiple template in Dreamweaver

Tags: templates, xhtml, dreamweaver

I have a site that was built in the late 90's. So I need to convert it over to modern times. In review of the site it has 798 pages total. I noticed it has 4 similar layouts. Is it possible to create one template in Dreamweaver for all 4 layouts. Or do I have build 4 templates (which is not a big deal...) ~ But it would be nice to have one template.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [nested templates](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7aa1a.html). You could have a master template for everything that the 4 layouts have in common, then make 4 layout-specific templates that derive from the master.

That way you can edit the different layouts in their own templates, but if you have to change code that is the same for all 4 you only have to do it in one place. And of course it's possible to nest even more levels into it, say if two of the layouts share some features. Although then an Optional Region in the master template might be better.

---

Keep in mind though that DW templates are not what most people associate with 'modern times', and the documentation is somewhat scarce. Using PHP includes or possibly [SSIs](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) may be something to consider instead.